# MySQL never asked for a password

Tags: mysql, sql

I am watching a YouTube tutorial on MySQL/SQL, and the installer in the video was much different than mine. It asked the instructor to make a password, but for me it did not. Now, whenever I try to open MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, it crashes immediately upon opening. How do I enter a password, and stop the application from crashing?

I used the Windows x86, 32 bit, MSI installer, and it closes when I try to open it. It is there for a quarter of a second, then it just closes, no error messages, nothing. I am going to the windows button, then clicking the icon that says "MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client".

Comment: You really need to provide us with more details. What installer did you use? What do you mean by "crashes"? Do you get an error message? Does it hang? How are you opening it: clicking an icon, or running a command? If the latter, what command?

Comment: Is that edit better?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have installed it properly, there should be MYSQL80 entry in services.
Search for services, then find MYSQL80(if you haven't changed the service name while installing mysql).
Make sure it is running. (Right click and start the service if not.)

Then, run cmd as administrator.

Then type "mysql_secure_installation" (without "").

And follow the prompts.

If you haven't setup your password then it should ask to enter new password.

After completion, try to run your command line client again.

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: I apparently did not install it correctly, do I have to start the installation process again?

Comment: Yes. But, if you only forgot to enter the password for root, then you can try above method. And did you try the above mentioned method? Thanks